# Modificar el DOM con ng-click

Tags: angularjs

Estoy intentando añadir un enlace que luego tiene que tener un ng-click en el interior (añadir o quitar cierta funcionalidad)

```
var enlace = '<a class="subEmpleado" ng-click="removeEmployee(user)"><i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i></a>';
var html = $("<p class='employed'>"+user.nombre+" "+user.apellidos+" "+enlace+ "</p>");
$('#anadidos').append(html);
var link_scope = angular.element(html).scope();
compile(html)(link_scope);
```

Los elementos se añaden correctamente al DOM, sin embargo no entra en la función `removeEmployeeUser`, parece que angular no está reconociendo el/los elemento/s que añado dinamicamente.

Extiendo el contenido:

```
    (function () {
        'use strict';
        var app = angular.module("MyApp", ["ngTable"]);

        app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $log, NgTableParams) {
            var self = this;
            var data = <?php echo $empleados; ?>;
            self.tableParams = new NgTableParams({count: 10}, {counts: [10, 25, 50, 100], dataset: data});

            $scope.count = 0;
            $scope.addEmployee = function(user){
                $scope.count++;

                var enlace = '<a class="subEmpleado" ng-click="removeEmployee(user)"><i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i></a>';
                var html = $("<p class='employed'>"+user.nombre+" "+user.apellidos+" "+enlace+ "</p>");
                $('#anadidos').append(html);
                var link_scope = angular.element(html).scope();
                compile(html)(link_scope);


                $("#frm_empleados").append("<input type='hidden' name='idempleado[]' value='" + user.idEmpleado + "'/>  ");
            };

            $scope.removeEmployee = function(user){
                //$scope.count--;
                $scope.count = 'user';
            };


        });
```

Comment: En que contexto estas ejecutando el codigo? [Hice una prueba en con una directiva](http://jsbin.com/qipuxobici/edit?html,js,output) y funciono correctamente. Tendras que mostrarnos mas codigo

Comment: Pues en una tabla de angular tengo un listado de empleados. Cuando clico sobre uno de ellos, se añaden a una zona, donde se muestran los que se van a mostrar en cierto informe. Lo que quiero es que al añadir ese enlace te permita borrar ese usuario del informe por si te has equivocado al añadirlo.

Comment: No has definido el servicio `compile`. O lo tienes global?

Comment: Si pruebo lo siguiente: app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $compile, NgTableParams) sigue sin funcionar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que definir el servicio [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) en tu controlador:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $log, NgTableParams, $compile)
```

Y en el metodo que genera el html:

```
$compile(html)(link_scope);
```

Comment: Gracias, lo he probado pero continua sin funcionarme

Comment: Preciona F12 -> Consola y dinos el error

Comment: Lo siento pero no me sale ningún error en la consola..